# What's the difference between MOCK_DECLARE_METHOD and MOCK_METHOD

Tags: c++, googletest

I mentioned, that some people using GTest declare Mock objects with
MOCK_DECLARE_METHOD and some with MOCK_METHOD.
What's the difference? As for me, MOCK_METHOD is better, no need of *.cpp file with MOCK_DEFINE_METHOD

Comment: For the same reasons you put declarations in header files and implementations in multiple cpp files. When your projects get larger, you appreciate this separation.

Comment: Is there no any other reasons?

Comment: As your projects become larger this starts to become the only reason. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`MOCK_METHOD()` is more convenient, but a lot of code will be compiled for every compilation unit (~ .cpp file) that includes it (even transitively). This can get quite slow.

With `MOCK_DECLARE_METHOD()` and `MOCK_DEFINE_METHOD()` you put `MOCK_DECLARE_METHOD()` in your header file and that's reasonably fast to compile again and again; and you put the corresponding `MOCK_DEFINE_METHOD()` into a single .cpp file, which will be rather slow to compile, but needs to be compiled only once.

Note: It seems that starting with GTest 1.8.1. `MOCK_DECLARE_METHOD`/`MOCK_DEFINE_METHOD` are gone and `MOCK_METHOD` is the only option.

Comment: Header files don't get compiled; they get included. All else being equal, and starting from a blank slate, compile speed shouldn't be affected whether a function is defined inline in a header or compiled in a separate translation unit. After that, it stands to be faster because a build system can avoid recompiling if it's unchanged.

Comment: @underscore_d yes, headers get included; but *once included* into a translation unit their code gets *compiled* - again and again for every translation unit they get included into. In contrast, the function defined in a .cpp file directly only gets compiled once in total. That repeated compilation of the inline function can cause a significant compilation slowdown.